# Rest Api Best practice - Passing date as query param

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am writing a rest service using NodeJs and express middleware. I have below questions -

1. I have to take userid and token for authentication in every service irrespective of the method type i.e. `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`. What is the best way to take these two param i.e  as request header or query param? I don't want to take it as body params since the get requests wouldn't have the body.
2. I want to write a service with method type `GET` for data retrieval, the params for this call are string and a date. How shoule I pass the params as query parameter for this, specifically the date param should i pass it as js date or any other format?

   ```
   GET - https://localhost:someport/<objectid>/<createddate>
   headers - x-user-id:someid
             x-access-token:sometoken
   ```

   if this then which format the created date should be passed.

   or should I use the below one?

   ```
   GET - https://localhost:someport/
   headers - x-user-id:someid
             x-access-token:sometoken
             x-object-id:someid
             x-created-date:somedate
   ```

Comment: Put token in header and user id as get or post param.

Comment: token in header make sense but what you mean by user id as get or post param? The service has to be get so post is out of question. Now get has only headers and query param which one do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest to keep user id as query param. And a note on totally unrelated topic if you want to support post also then same request with query param and no body would work

Comment: Thanks @ArpitSolanki for the help, I have updated the question may I have your views on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request header is the best place to send those kind of sensitive information. Header is common in all method of http request. Therefor you don't want to worry about the method like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`. if you use query parameters, it will we more ugly in the urls. 
 Additionally, I have no idea of the usage of `UserID` with `token`. Because in restful server we use the token to identify the user also. Therefor in general we don't send user id.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and that completely sounds valid not to use userid with token. I am using jwt for your info and already passing user id in token. I can get rid of user id. So thats one param less, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The best practices for a rest API design says that expose the parameters which are not sensitive user information to get request as query params. So user id and token like things should go in header and other things can go in get request params.

Choose the first one which has only user id and token in headers.

Comment: I agree with that, however the question is does complex data type like date should be passed as query param?

Comment: Yeah date can be passed in query params. Just make sure that your date format does not have any character that conflicts with reserved URL characters